# Comparing Numbers Two number in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I don't know where the problem is: when I execute this, I get an error:

```
./script.sh: line 4: if[ 7 -gt 5 ]: command not found  
./script.sh: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token then'
./script.sh: line 5: `then'
```

---

```
#!/bin/bash
read a
read b
if[ $a -gt $b ]
then
echo "$a is greater than $b"
elif [ $a -lt $b ]
then
echo "$a is less than $b"
else
echo "$a is equal to $b"
fi
```

Comment: As the bash tag wiki suggests, you should run your code through http://shellcheck.net/ before asking questions here.

Comment: Note that spacing is crucial in the shell.  You must be very careful with it — neither too much nor too little.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for `if` in bash follows:

```
if COMMANDS; then COMMANDS; [ elif COMMANDS; then COMMANDS; ]... [ else COMMANDS; ] fi
```

Note the space following `if`; it is **mandatory**. Note also that `[` isn't any kind of special syntax; it's just a command, same as `ls` or `grep`. You can't type `ifgrep`, so you can't type `if[` either.

Because `if[` is not `if`, you weren't in an `if` block, so `then` was unexpected, thus your syntax error.

---

Thus:

```
if [ "$a" -gt "$b" ]   # Correct
```

not

```
if ["$a" -gt "$b" ]    # Wrong because of lack of space
```

or

```
if[ $a -gt $b ]        # Wrong because of lack of space and lack of quotes
```

(Leaving the quotes out leaves you open to a completely separate set of bugs).